# How to pass an ssh key passphrase via environment variable

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, ssh-keys, ssh-agent

I run shell script with `ssh` command inside my application. Used private key is encrypted by passphrase and the problem is - I cannot interactively pass it when asked.Key is not added in `ssh-agent`. I cannot execute `ssh-add my_key` because the passphrase is suppose to be passed interactively. It's good for terminal communication, but not so good to use inside application.

The `man page` says:

> DISPLAY and SSH_ASKPASS
>
> If ssh-add needs a passphrase, it will read the passphrase from the current terminal if it was run from a terminal.
>                If ssh-add does not have a terminal associated with it but DISPLAY and SSH_ASKPASS are set, it will execute the
>                program specified by SSH_ASKPASS and open an X11 window to read the passphrase.  This is particularly useful when
>                calling ssh-add from a .xsession or related script.  (Note that on some machines it may be necessary to redirect
>                the input from /dev/null to make this work.)

When I execute `SSH_ASKPASS=file_with_passphrase ssh-add my_key` I still asked to type a passphrase, looks like env var is just ignored in that case. I tryed to execute `ssh -o BatchMode=yes` and server just rejected encoded key because no one was able to decoded it.

I definitely can decode ssh key manually before using it in `ssh-agent` but it looks like I'm about to get what I need from `SSH_ASKPASS` variable, but I don't know how to make it work. Happy to get community help.

Comment: You say `When I execute SSH_ASKPASS=file_with_passphrase ssh-add my_key I still asked to type a passphrase` - but this is not really what the man page says - the file must be executable and output the password on stdout - so it should be something like `echo "echo 'your_password'" > /tmp/unsafe; chmod +x /tmp/unsafe; SSH_ASKPASS=/tmp/unsafe ssh-add my_key`. As an example of something that can be used in `SSH_ASKPASS` see `x11-ssh-askpass` command - you can check out its man page and also run it to see how it behaves.

Comment: @IwanAucamp Oh thanks, misunderstood, made a script instead of file.
And it didn't help btw

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So there are actually a few things that is important for what you are trying to do:

1. DISPLAY must be set
2. it must not have a terminal associated with it
3. on some machines it may be necessary to redirect the input from /dev/null (mine is one of them).
4. SSH_ASKPASS must contain an executable which outputs the passphrase on `stdout`.

So for an example of getting it to work (for me, should work on other linux also I guess):

Create dummy key:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C se-so-38354773 -f /tmp/se-so-38354773.key -N 'se-so-38354773-pp'
```

Create askpass script to echo password files:

```
cat > /tmp/se-so-38354773-askpass <<EOF
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "${0}:${@} : this is for debugging to see if the echo script runs" 1>&2
echo "se-so-38354773-pp"
EOF
chmod +x /tmp/se-so-38354773-askpass
```

I placed this file in /tmp/ - but this is not a good for security unless you also change permissions on the file before writing to it to ensure that nobody else can read it (or set umask).

Then you can do ssh-add as follow:

```
DISPLAY=":0.0" SSH_ASKPASS="/tmp/se-so-38354773-askpass" setsid ssh-add /tmp/se-so-38354773.key </dev/null
```

The `setsid` dissociates it from your terminal if there is one - This is not needed on my computer though - but yeah - I think it may be needed in some other contexts.

And when you are done testing do clean up:

```
ssh-add -d /tmp/se-so-38354773.key
rm /tmp/se-so-38354773*
```

Example output on my computer:

```
iwana@iwana-nb.concurrent.co.za:~/projects/gitlab.com/aucampia/stackexchange/stackoverflow/38354773
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -C se-so-38354773 -f /tmp/se-so-38354773.key -N 'se-so-38354773-pp'
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Your identification has been saved in /tmp/se-so-38354773.key.
Your public key has been saved in /tmp/se-so-38354773.key.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:s+jVUPEyb2DzRM5y+Hm3XDzVRREKn5yU2d0hk61hIQ0 se-so-38354773
The key's randomart image is:
+---[RSA 2048]----+
|          .E+=B=O|
|           B*B*o=|
|          X B*o o|
|         o % o ..|
|        S   * ..+|
|       . = . ...+|
|      . o .    o |
|     . .         |
|      .          |
+----[SHA256]-----+
iwana@iwana-nb.concurrent.co.za:~/projects/gitlab.com/aucampia/stackexchange/stackoverflow/38354773
$ 
iwana@iwana-nb.concurrent.co.za:~/projects/gitlab.com/aucampia/stackexchange/stackoverflow/38354773
$ cat > /tmp/se-so-38354773-askpass <<EOF
> #!/usr/bin/env bash
> echo "${0}:${@} : this is for debugging to see if the echo script runs" 1>&2
> echo "se-so-38354773-pp"
> EOF
iwana@iwana-nb.concurrent.co.za:~/projects/gitlab.com/aucampia/stackexchange/stackoverflow/38354773
$ chmod +x /tmp/se-so-38354773-askpass
iwana@iwana-nb.concurrent.co.za:~/projects/gitlab.com/aucampia/stackexchange/stackoverflow/38354773
$ 
iwana@iwana-nb.concurrent.co.za:~/projects/gitlab.com/aucampia/stackexchange/stackoverflow/38354773
$ DISPLAY=":0.0" SSH_ASKPASS="/tmp/se-so-38354773-askpass" setsid ssh-add /tmp/se-so-38354773.key </dev/null
iwana@iwana-nb.concurrent.co.za:~/projects/gitlab.com/aucampia/stackexchange/stackoverflow/38354773
$ 
bash: : this is for debugging to see if the echo script runs
Identity added: /tmp/se-so-38354773.key (/tmp/se-so-38354773.key)
iwana@iwana-nb.concurrent.co.za:~/projects/gitlab.com/aucampia/stackexchange/stackoverflow/38354773
$ ssh-add -d /tmp/se-so-38354773.key
Identity removed: /tmp/se-so-38354773.key (se-so-38354773)
iwana@iwana-nb.concurrent.co.za:~/projects/gitlab.com/aucampia/stackexchange/stackoverflow/38354773
$ rm /tmp/se-so-38354773*
```

Comment: `user@imnc:~/Code/Sandbox$ chmod +x passphrase.sh `
`user@imnc:~/Code/Sandbox$ DISPLAY=":0.0" SSH_ASKPASS=./passphrase.sh setsid ssh-add encrypted_key` 
`Enter passphrase for encrypted_key: `
No idea why but I still getting asked to enter a passphrase. Didn't work either

Comment: Oh, sorry again, missed dev/null redirection, it is working actually. Thanks a lot

Comment: It seems too tricky to achieve so simple requirement and also unsecure as hell. Wonder how people solve such problem.

Comment: @SergeyVoitovich Can you maybe elaborate on your use case a bit ? I only had to use this once ever and that was actually not for adding a key but for passing a password to ssh since the endpoint was running some custom ssh solution with no support for key based auth available to me. If you have automated use cases the right approach in most cases is to not use a passphrase and just restrict access to keys and also restrict access in authorized keys file. See https://serverfault.com/questions/142959 for some discussion.

Comment: sure: distributed java web application, one instance fetches repo from another one using git via ssh. Generally `ssh key` is not known for `ssh agent``. Inside I  call native git and pass key with `GIT_SSH` environment variable. `GIT_SSH` is set to bash script, which calls native ssh. In order to support windows I can't use something except `git bash` supports (sadly, I don't know a lot about it). The key may be encrypted and my app asked to provide a pasphrase and I was in a search to satisfy this need:)

Comment: set `SSH_ASKPASS_REQUIRE=force` instead of `DISPLAY`

Answer (score 2):

Edit: I am adding more details to this answer.  If you have a PEM encoded private key with a password you can use openssl to decrypt the key first, as openssl will accept a passphrase on stdin.

To generate a new key that will work with this use this command:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -m pem -b 4096
```

It cannot be an 'OPENSSH' key.  The start of an existing key that looks like this should work.

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-128-CBC,8032BCA01FB25FCCD89AFDED8DB52079
```

Then, you can use openssl to decrypt the key before sending it to ssh-add.  Openssl accepts the passphrase on stdin with the `-passin stdin` option and will by default output to stdout, then ssh-add can accept the unencrypted key on stdin by adding a `-` as the first argument.

```
echo "$MY_PASSPHRASE" | openssl rsa -in my_encrypted_key -passin stdin | ssh-add -
```

Comment: Be more specific about the answer.