# How to sftp into a server and pass a pem key passphrase automatically with linux script?

Tags: linux, rsa, sftp

I'm trying to create a linux script that can be called to automatically sftp into an external server using a pem key which has an associated passphrase?

As far as I can tell it would be roughly something like:

sftp -i rsa_private.pem -p rsa_private_passphrase username@ip_address

But obviously this is passing in an assumed password for the sftp account and not for the pem key... I'm relatively inexperienced with linux scripting so any help at all would be highly appreciated!

Comment: See [How to run the sftp command with a password from Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5386482/850848)

Comment: So that question is asking about the sftp password, whereas I'm asking about a passphrase which has been imparted on the .pem file?

Comment: Sure, I'm aware of that. But the solutions are pretty much the same. Except that you have an additional option of simply removing the passphrase from the key or loading the key to agent or keychain.

Answer (score 0):

Try this tricky solution :
[How to pass an ssh key passphrase via environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38354773/)

basically , you have to follow these steps :
install ssh-agent first

**Create a shell script askpass.sh containing the passphrase**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "${0}:${@} : this is for debugging to see if the echo script runs" 1>&2
echo "THEPASSPHRASE"
```

**From your sftp script , start ssh-agent and launch the helper script**

```
#start the agent
eval $(ssh-agent)

#add your privatekey with ssh-add and the helper script
DISPLAY=":0.0" SSH_ASKPASS="/scripts/askpass.sh" setsid ssh-add /scripts/priv.key </dev/null

#start your sftp session with the privatekey
sftp -v -i /scripts/priv.key  user@sftp.yourserver.com
```